# Pressing the escape key on an open Select2 dropdown shouldn't close Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-select2

Using Twitter Bootstrap 3, a Select2 dropdown is embedded within a modal.
Now when pressing the escape key on such an *opened* Select2 element both the dropdown **and** the modal dialog are getting closed immediately.

How can I prevent the modal to be closed in such a case?
However, it's fine to close the modal when pressing the escape key in case the current focused dropdown is **closed**. Therefore in the above described situation it would need two escape key presses: The first which closes the dropdown and a second one which close the modal.

I prepared a jsfiddle to easily reproduce the behaviour http://jsfiddle.net/a82RX/.
(I used the same modal like in the bootstrap documentation with a very simple select2 dropdown.)

I already tried to interfere and cancel the closing of the modal by listening on the

```
  select2-close
```

event, with no success.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
  $('#myModal').modal({keyboard:false});
```

Refer http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage

Complete Solution:

HTML

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="modalLaunch">Launch demo modal</button>
```

Script:

```
$(function() {
    $("#e1").select2();
    $("#modalLaunch").click(function() {
        $('#myModal').modal({
            show:true,
            keyboard:false,
            backdrop:'static'
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But that was not what I was looking for. keyboard:false completely disables the esc key functionality, but I just want it to be disabled after I press esc on an open select2 dropdown, so only the dropdown gets closed. However it's fine to close the modal when hitting the esc key and the dropdown is closed.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ravimallya/a82RX/14/ is this what you wanted to achieve? here I used `$("#e1").on("select2-close", function () {
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
});` to hide the modal after selecting any option from the select element. You can combine [events](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/select2-latest.html#events) of select2 with bootstrap modal javascript to get.

Comment: No this isn't what I want to achive. Maybe I didnt explain it clear enough (I'm not native in english). What I want to achive is kind of the opposite, like this: "When the dropdown is open and hitting esc, ONLY the dropdown should be closed now, but the modal should stay opened". Thanks anyway for you efforts.

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm struggling with the exact same problem right now.

Comment: Well 8 Years later and I seem to have the same Problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I came across this sort of a situation too and I found a solution for this problem. It is a combination of different ideas.

1) When showing modal, set keyboard to false. Code is exactly what @ravimallya has provided.

2) Listen to the 'esc' keyup event. (I guess you can also listen to keydown/keypress event but I went with keyup)

```
var ESCAPE_KEY = 27;
$('#myModal').on('keyup', function (event) {
    if (event.which === ESCAPE_KEY) {
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    }
});
```

3) [Bonus] I have also implemented double escape to close modal functionality, which was not so obvious so decided to share it with everyone. Basically when the focus is on the select2 and the dropdown is open, when you press 'Esc', the select2 dropdown closes. However if you press 'Esc' again, nothing happens. While the behavior of the second 'Esc' is correct, I would prefer it to close the modal. So here is my code implementation of it:

```
$('#mySelect').select2();
var mySelectContainer = $(mySelect).data('select2').container;
$(mySelectContainer).on('keyup', function (event) {
    if (event.which === KeyCodes.Escape) {
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    }
});
```

The reason why listening to select2-close event doesn't work is because the modal's keyup (or something like it) handler triggers immediately after an 'esc' has occurred.

Btw, if you happen to find yourself subscribing to a lot of keyup/keydown/keypress events, you might want to check out [JQuery HotKeys](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys). And if you are already using it, then the above solution looks like the following:

```
$('#myModal').on('keyup', null, 'esc', function () {
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
});
```

Comment: I had identical problem and this solution worked like a charm. @mkurz - you should make this answer as the best one :)

Answer (score 0):

This answer is quite late but I thought I would still post my solution here since I had the same problem today. My select2 dropdown closed the modal when you tried closing the open dropdown with the escape key.
To solve this behavior I added an event listener wich checks if an escape key gets pressed on the open dropdown. If yes it shoud stop the Propagation and close the dropdown with the `select2.('close')` method.

```
 $(document).on('select2:open', () => {

    window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        let dropdown = $('.select2-hidden-accessible');
        if ((e.key === 'Escape' || e.key === 'Esc') && $('.select2-container--open').length) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            dropdown.select2('close');
            return false;
        }
    }, true);
});
```